# How stream.sorted() works when pipelining a stream?

Tags: java

The below code when executed

```
Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.of(10,2,7);
Stream<Integer> intStream2 = intStream.filter(n -> { System.out.println("Filtering Current Element: "+n); return n % 2 == 0; });
Stream<Integer> intStream3 = intStream2.map(n -> { System.out.println("Mapping Current Element: "+n); return n * n * n; });
intStream3.forEach(a->System.out.println(a));
```

Gives output as

```
Filtering Current Element: 10
Mapping Current Element: 10
1000
Filtering Current Element: 2
Mapping Current Element: 2
8
Filtering Current Element: 7
```

But when sorted is used in between

```
Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.of(10,2,7);
Stream<Integer> intStream2 = intStream.filter(n -> { System.out.println("Filtering Current Element: "+n); return n % 2 == 0; });
Stream<Integer> intStream3 = intStream2.map(n -> { System.out.println("Mapping Current Element: "+n); return n * n * n; });
intStream3.sorted().forEach(a->System.out.println(a));
```

The output is this

```
Filtering Current Element: 10
Mapping Current Element: 10
Filtering Current Element: 2
Mapping Current Element: 2
Filtering Current Element: 7
8
1000
```

Can someone explain how the stream flows through this pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate operations on `Stream`s (like `filter`, `map`, `sorted`) are evaluated lazily; they are not applied until there is a terminal operation like `forEach`. In the case of `filter` and `map` before `forEach`, the operations can be applied sequentially from the first element to the last. However, `sorted` requires operating on all elements of the `Stream` first to sort it, after which `forEach` can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

When you call stream operations inside, they are called in parallel thread.

And when you call sorted() - it do the sort in it's own thread, and then returns result into current thread.

So in the last example you do 2 operations of **Stream** *sort()* and then *foreach()*